# Java jar file "no main manifest attribute"

Tags: java, powershell, jar

To start, I have looked at the similar questions posted about this topic. I have not found a solution.

I wish to distribute a small project I have been working on to friends and family. Trouble is I can't expect them all to be able to run .class files. Therefore I am trying to produce a .jar file that I can turn into an .exe file. I am however running into an issue. It complains about missing the main manifest attribute. After some googling, I resolved to try a little [tutorial](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html). I am following the tutorial (even downloading the little Hello.jar file), but still I get no main manifest attribute.

As I am running Windows 10, I am using PowerShell to run commands. This is the commands I've run:

```
PS C:\testJarFraNettet> javac Hello.java
PS C:\testJarFraNettet> jar cmf Hello.mf Hello.jar Hello.class Hello.java
PS C:\testJarFraNettet> java -jar Hello.jar
no main manifest attribute, in Hello.jar
PS C:\testJarFraNettet>
```

You'll notice I've included the .java file in the .jar as well, just to be sure.

Hello.mf contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Hello
```

I investigated the .jar file that gets produced. Inside, among the files specified in the command, I find the expected .\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF file with the following content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 17.0.1 (Eclipse Adoptium)
```

I've never touched Eclipse (I use VS Code), but I assume this is of no consequence.
Per another article I found online, I edited the file to instead contain what the tutorial tells me it should contain:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Hello
```

Still no luck. I've decided against showing my own code, as it needlessly complicates troubleshooting since I get the same error anyways. I still have some hurdles left, such as how to add image files. The project is a GUI based game. But that is an issue for later, I suppose.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `Eclipse Adoptium` is the name of your JVM, it has nothing to do with eclipse-the-editor. Presumably, the jar tool includes its own JVM release if there's no other manifest, or adds it. NB: VS Code __is__ Eclipse, at least, it uses eclipse for all java-specific things, under the hood. Not that it's related here, 'Eclipse Adoptium' refers to your JVM, not the editor.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I find so many tangential things related to programming mystifying, which is a bit of a bummer because I am addicted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jar cfe Hello.jar Hello Hello.class Hello.java
```

will do it for you. You need to point the `-e` parameter to the main class so that `jar` knows how to make it executable. This is easier than making your own manifest

Comment: Thank you again, you are a life saver! Do you perhaps know why the tutorial would use cmf? It seems to be from a reputable site (princeton.edu), and I am just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Probably an old tutorial. The `-e` parameter arrived relatively recently. Not exactly sure when